# py2exe Installer crashes

Tags: python, crash, installation, py2exe

I wrote a Python GUI script with Tkinter, and now I want to convert it to a standalone .exe.
I have already used py2exe on another pc with WinXP, but on my own pc, where I use Win7 32bit, I can't indtall it. I took the original installer from py2exe.org for 32bit, but when I start it, after half a minute or so it says "py2exe doesn't work anymore" and then the installer crashes.
What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I figured it out. I had to run the installer as Admin, not as normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try using Pyinstaller. It worked better than py2exe in my case to make a standalone .exe from Tkinter

Comment: Thanks, I am using PyInstaller now.